# How to assign event trigger pointer click as Fire1 in Google VR Cardboard Unity 2019

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr, 360-virtual-reality

I've finish my VR Cardboards game using Unity 2019 but the problem is I forgot to declare every click action with controller with Input.GetKeyDown("Fire1"). I was assigned all click-event with event trigger Pointer Click. So I can't play this game with controller.

[Example of Event Trigger Pointer Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv1Nt.png)
There's any way to get me out from this?

Answer (score 0):

Case closed by myself.
Use this script and put to the interactable object with pointer click.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PointerTrigger : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler,IPointerExitHandler
{
    bool active = false;
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        active = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        active = false;
    }


    private void Update()
    {

        if (active && Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Fired");

            var pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
            ExecuteEvents.Execute(gameObject, pointer, ExecuteEvents.pointerClickHandler);
        }
    }

}
```